# I can not update my data

Tags: apex, visualforce

Image of my object in salesforce
[image]

I want to update the information contained in my "var" variable in my "Principale__c" object, using this function

```
public void DMLOperation () {

List <Principale__c> letter = getValo ();
List <Principale__c> updateList = new List <Principale__c> ();

for (Principale__c opps: letter) {
    updateList.add (opps);
    system.debug (opps);
}
 update (sObject []) updateList;
}
```

But when I do a debug of my valriable "letter" I do not see any value.
What I would like to do is to be able to update the data that is in my variable

("(Principale__c: {Id = a0A1i000001VoH8EAK, CodeAlliance__c = wzgr6301}, Principle__c: {Id = a0A1i000001VoHIEA0, CodeAlliance__c = hqdl8921}, Principle__c: {Id = a0A1i000001VoHSEA0, CodeAlliance__c = lqlp8695} Principale__c: {Id = a0A1i000001VoHXEA0, CodeAlliance__c = cfjk9062} Principale__c: {Id = a0A1i000001VoHhEAK, CodeAlliance__c = bjqb3665} Principale__c: {Id = a0A1i000001VoHmEAK, CodeAlliance__c = mtds9152} Principale__c: {Id = a0A1i000001VoI1EAK , CodeAlliance__c = proy0003} ")"

from my "Principale__c" object because the "CodeAlliance" field, the data is incomplete.
Here is the code that returns the data I want to update in my "Principale__c" object

```
public List<Principale__c> getValo(){

List<Principale__c> searchList = new   List<Principale__c>();
List<Principale__c> var = new List<Principale__c>();
for (integer l = 0; l < data.size(); l++) {
    searchList=[SELECT id From Principale__c where Email__c=:data[l][0]];
    system.debug(searchList);
    for (Principale__c principalProd :searchList) {
        principalProd.CodeAlliance__c = data[l][1];
        var.add(principalProd);
    }               
 }
    system.debug(var);
    return var;
}
```

I show you all my code

```
public class ImportExcel {  
public String fileName{get; set;}
public Blob contentFile{get;set;}
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public List<List<String>> data; 
public List<String> mails;
List<Principale__c> searchList;
List<Principale__c> var;
public ImportExcel(){
    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    data= new List<List<String>>();
    searchList= new List<Principale__c>();
    var=new List<Principale__c>();
} 
public void readFile(){
    try
    {
        fileName=contentFile.toString();       
        csvFileLines = fileName.split('\n'); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Please upload a valid CSV document');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
        return ; 
    }      
} 
//retourne la liste des données parcourues
public List<List<String>> getVal(){
    String[] data2; 
    for(integer i=0;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
        data2=csvFileLines[i].split(',');
        //instancie la liste
        List<String> tampon = new List<String>();
        for(integer j=0; j<data2.size();j++){
          tampon.add(data2[j]);
        }
        data.add(tampon); 
    }
    return data;  
}   
//recupère le tableau des E-mails
public List<String> getMail(){
    List<List<String>> var = data;
    List<String> tampon = new List<String>();
    for(integer k=0;k<var.size();k++){
        tampon.add(var[k][0]);
    }
    //system.debug(tampon);
    mails = tampon;
    return tampon;
}


public  List<Principale__c> getValo(){
    system.debug(data.size());
for(integer l=0;l<data.size();l++){
        searchList=[SELECT id From Principale__c where Email__c=:data[l][0]];
        for(Principale__c principalProd :searchList){
            principalProd.CodeAlliance__c=data[l][1];
            var.add(principalProd);
        }   
}
    system.debug(var);
return var; 
}

public void DMLOperation() {  
List<Principale__c> lettre= getValo();
List<Principale__c> updateList = new List<Principale__c>();
system.debug(lettre);
    for(Principale__c opps: lettre){
        updateList.add(opps);
    }
update (sObject[]) updateList;
}
}
```

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="ImportExcel">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
               <apex:inputFile value="{!contentFile}"  filename="{!fileName}"/>
               <apex:commandButton value="Import Excel" action="{!readFile}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!val}" var="acct">
                   <apex:column value="{!acct}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock>   
            <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mail}" var="liste">
                   <apex:column value="{!liste}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock> 
               <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!valo}" var="li">
                   <apex:column value="{!li}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock> 
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93430/discussion-on-question-by-corentin-kounou-i-can-not-update-my-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this documentation [Considerations for Creating Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_considerations.htm?search_text=dml)

> You can't use data manipulation language (DML) operations in a
>   “getxxx” method in a controller. For example, if your controller had a
>   getName method, you could not use insert or update in the method to
>   create an object

As you are trying to update the records in the `getxxx` method in a controller, that records won't be updated.

You will have to perform the update operation on click of `Import Excel` button. So, this is how your controller and visualforce page should look like to make this to work.

**Updated controller**

```
public class ImportExcel {  
    public String fileName{get; set;}
    public Blob contentFile{get;set;}
    public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
    public List<List<String>> data; 
    public List<String> mails;
    List<Principale__c> searchList;
    List<Principale__c> var;
    public List<List<String>> Val {get;set;}
    public List<Contact> Valo {get;set;}
    public List<List<String>> Val1 {get;set;}
    public List<Contact> Valo1 {get;set;}

    public ImportExcel(){
        csvFileLines = new String[]{};
        data= new List<List<String>>();
        searchList= new List<Principale__c>();
        var=new List<Principale__c>();
    } 

    public void readFile(){
        try
        {
            fileName=contentFile.toString();       
            csvFileLines = fileName.split('\n'); 
            Val1 = getValMethod();
            Valo1 = getValoMethod();
            List<Principale__c>  principaleToUpdate = Valo1;
            update principaleToUpdate;
        }catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Please upload a valid CSV document');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
            return ; 
        }      
    } 

    //retourne la liste des données parcourues
    public List<List<String>> getValMethod(){
        String[] data2; 
        for(integer i=0;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
            data2=csvFileLines[i].split(',');
            //instancie la liste
            List<String> tampon = new List<String>();
            for(integer j=0; j<data2.size();j++){
              tampon.add(data2[j]);
            }
            data.add(tampon); 
        }
        return data;  
    }   

    //recupère le tableau des E-mails
    public List<String> getMail(){
        List<List<String>> var = data;
        List<String> tampon = new List<String>();
        for(integer k=0;k<var.size();k++){
            tampon.add(var[k][0]);
        }
        //system.debug(tampon);
        mails = tampon;
        return tampon;
    }

    public  List<Principale__c> getValoMethod(){
        system.debug(data.size());
        for(integer l=0;l<data.size();l++){
            searchList=[SELECT id From Principale__c where Email__c=:data[l][0]];
            for(Principale__c principalProd :searchList){
                principalProd.CodeAlliance__c=data[l][1];
                var.add(principalProd);
            }   
        }
        system.debug(var);
        return var; 
    }

    /*public void DMLOperation() {  
        List<Principale__c> lettre= getValo();
        List<Principale__c> updateList = new List<Principale__c>();
        system.debug(lettre);
            for(Principale__c opps: lettre){
                updateList.add(opps);
            }
        update (sObject[]) updateList;
    }*/
}
```

**Updated visualforce page**

```
<apex:page controller="ImportExcel">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
               <apex:inputFile value="{!contentFile}"  filename="{!fileName}"/>
               <apex:commandButton value="Import Excel" action="{!readFile}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!val1}" var="acct">
                   <apex:column value="{!acct}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock>   
            <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mail}" var="liste">
                   <apex:column value="{!liste}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock> 
               <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!valo1}" var="li">
                   <apex:column value="{!li}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock> 
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Note :** Save the controller first and then save the visualforce page. I updated few variables names, i.e. `val` and `valo` to `val1` and `valo1` respectively. Post saving the visualforce page, you can revert the variables names if needed from visualforce page and controller.